# Shortest distance in km google map

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i use this script in google sheets to calculate my mileage charges.

```
    /**
* Get Distance between 2 different addresses.
* @param start_address Address as string Ex. "300 N LaSalles St, Chicago, IL"
* @param end_address Address as string Ex. "900 N LaSalles St, Chicago, IL"
* @param return_type Return type as string Ex. "miles" or "kilometers" or "minutes" or "hours"
* @customfunction
*/

function GOOGLEMAPS(start_address,end_address,return_type) {

  // https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/
  // Nov 2017
  // improvements needed
  
  var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();
  
  var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];
  
  var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];
  
  switch(return_type){
    case "miles":
      return meters * 0.000621371;
      break;
    case "minutes":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to minutes and return
        return duration / 60;
      break;
    case "hours":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to hours and return
        return duration / 60 / 60;
      break;      
    case "kilometers":
      return meters / 1000;
      break;
    default:
      return "Error: Wrong Unit Type";
   }
  
}
```

that works fine, but I would like the script to choose the shortest route in distance and not in time, like in this example :

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

It gives me 22.7km but I would like it to give me the shortest distance each time, in this case 21.3km

What can I change in the script so that it takes the shortest route in distance and not in time? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the minimum distance.
- You want to achieve this using a custom function of Google Apps Script.

In this case, in order to retrieve the multiple routes, I used `setAlternatives(useAlternatives)`. And, the minimum distance is retrieved from the retrieved multiple routes.

When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows. Please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];

var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];
```

#### To:

```
var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder().setAlternatives(true);
mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
var directions = mapObj.getDirections();
var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];
var meters = Math.min(...directions.routes.map(({legs: [{distance: {value}}]}) => value));
```

- If you want to use the value of `getTheLeg` from the same `routes` of `meters`, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
      mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
      mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
      var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

      var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];

      var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder().setAlternatives(true);
      mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
      mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
      var directions = mapObj.getDirections();
      var {getTheLeg, meters} = directions.routes.map(({legs: [{duration, distance}]}) => ({duration, distance})).reduce((o, {duration, distance}, i) => {
        if (i == 0 || o.meters > distance.value) {
          o.meters = distance.value;
          o.getTheLeg.duration.value = duration.value;
        }
        return o;
      }, {getTheLeg: {duration: {value: 0}}, meters: 0});
    ```

#### Note:

- In this case, please enable the V8 runtime of the Google Apps Script project, if you didn't enable it.

#### References:

- [setAlternatives(useAlternatives)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/direction-finder#setalternativesusealternatives)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!