# Using Apps Script to find longest route using Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script

So I have a small script that I am using to find the distance between locations using Maps. Most people would want to use the shortest recommended route, but I am trying to find the longest. Here is the start of the current script:

```
function googlemaps (start_address, end_address) {

start_address = "Starbucks, 799 A St, Hayward, CA 94541";
end_address = "Hayward BART Station, 699 B St, Hayward, CA 94541";

var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
mapObj.setDestination(end_address);

var directions = mapObj.getDirections();
Logger.log(directions["routes"]);
Logger.log(directions["routes"].length);

};
```

When I look on Google maps for the directions of the above address, I can see that there are three possible routes, but when I try to find the length of the array, it just says 1. I'm not sure what I am missing

Comment: are you setting `alternatives` to true in the request to the service? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#alternatives

Comment: `length` is a property of `Array.prototype` that returns the number of elements of the Array assigned to `directions["routes"]`, not the "length" of of the route. What you need is the get the property(ies) `distance`.  Add `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(directions["routes"]))` so you can see the data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your situation, you can retrieve other patterns using `setAlternatives(true)`. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69714894) This has also already been mentioned in the comment.
- In order to retrieve `the longest` you expect, it is required to retrieve it from the response values.

When these are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function googlemaps(start_address, end_address) {

  start_address = "Starbucks, 799 A St, Hayward, CA 94541";
  end_address = "Hayward BART Station, 699 B St, Hayward, CA 94541";

  var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
  mapObj.setAlternatives(true); // Added
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();
  var res = directions.routes.sort((a, b) => a.legs[0].distance.value > b.legs[0].distance.value ? -1 : 1)[0]; // Modified
  console.log(res.legs[0].distance.value); // Modified
  // console.log(res); // Here, you can see the object of `the longest`.
}
```

- When this script is run, you can retrieve the object of `the longest` as `res`. In this modification, in order to retrieve the object of `the longest`, I used `sort`.

#### References:

- [setAlternatives(useAlternatives)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/direction-finder#setalternativesusealternatives)
- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)